# how to prevent refresh on asp.net c# web page button?

Tags: asp.net

how to prevent refresh on asp.net c# web page button?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Regards

Comment: Do you mean a refresh of data if its a postback?? You need to make your question more descriptive as its difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Buttons are meant to post data to server in general. You can use Ajax at the most.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: <asp:Button OnClientClick="return false" OnClick="Button_Click" runat="server" /> , in that case the use of Button will be showpiece in your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use this way :

```
<asp:button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Button" onClientclick="btn_Click(event);">     </asp:button>
<script>

function btn_Click (e)
{

    if(//Check somthing)
          e.preventDefault();

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you can't.

However, using methods such as ajax, you can hide the appearance of the postback.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by creating a cookie inside your Button1_Click method. The first instruction within this method should check if that cookie exists or has not expired. In case itdoesn't exist or it expired, the follow line will create or update the cookie.  In case the cookie exists,
return;
Sorry i cant give code cause im using my mobile.